# Impossible to push docker images to gitlab: denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Tags: docker, gitlab, registry, gitlab-ce

First of all, I must tell this is an operation I have done many times, with no issues.

I have a docker image `registry.gitlab.com/company/metadata_api`  with `dev` tag.

```
➜  metadata_api git:(no_basic_auth) ✗ docker images | grep registry.gitlab.com/company/metadata_api
    registry.gitlab.com/company/metadata_api           dev                 80cdbdb33ec9        7 minutes ago       12.2MB
    registry.gitlab.com/company/metadata_api           latest              d9918d874a55        3 weeks ago         12.3MB
```

I have a deploy token for the project with both scopes `read_repository, read_registry`

I also have a global personal access token that I will use to discard rigths issues

```
➜  metadata_api git:(no_basic_auth) ✗ docker login registry.gitlab.com -u oauth2 
Password: 
Login Succeeded
```

When I try to push, I get :

```
requested access to the resource is denied
```

Why ?

```
➜  metadata_api git:(no_basic_auth) ✗ docker push registry.gitlab.com/company/metadata_api:dev
The push refers to repository [registry.gitlab.com/company/metadata_api]
a9ae54b0eb8c: Preparing 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a deploy token for the project with both scopes `read_repository`, `read_registry`
>
> [...]
>
> When I try to push, I get :
> `requested access to the resource is denied`

You lack the proper scope to push to registry (you only have read permission). With `deploy token`s you cannot push to registry, as per Gitlab indication on the Deploy Token page:

> Deploy tokens allow **read-only access** to your repository and registry images.

There an open [issue for `write_registry`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/47828) permissions on registry for Deploy Tokens being discussed.

Maybe try using an `access token` with scope `api`

Comment: api scope is for Personal Access Token, not for Deploy Token

Comment: I already tried to use a personal token with all rights on all repo  and it was not working...  As I answered before, a reboot fixed the issue. Je peux partir en week end :)

Answer (score 0):

I rebooted my computer, and it worked!